# (Plesk) Downloading file via RPC API

Tags: plesk

Is it possible to download files from Plesk server, using their RPC API (similarly to **Uploading files to server**)? Or should I use FTP for transfer instead (or other supported transport protocol)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is only "download-file" operation in Plesk API RPC, but it is only in scope of backup files operation - http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/44588.htm
So, use FTP transfer if you mean other files.